# Django: Increment blog entry view count by one. Is this efficient?

Tags: python, database, django, performance

I have the following code in my index view.

```
latest_entry_list = Entry.objects.filter(is_published=True).order_by('-date_published')[:10]
for entry in latest_entry_list:
    entry.views = entry.views + 1
    entry.save()
```

If there are ten (the limit) rows returned from the initial query, will the save issue 10 seperate updated calls to the database, or is Django "smart" enough to issue just one update call?

Is there a more efficient method to achieve this result?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use `F()` objects for this.

Here is how you import `F`: `from django.db.models import F`

**[New in Django 1.1](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once).**
Calls to update can also use F() objects to update one field based on the value of another field in the model. This is especially useful for incrementing counters based upon their current value.

```
Entry.objects.filter(is_published=True).update(views=F('views')+1)
```

Although you can't do an update on a sliced query set... **edit: actually you can...**

This can be done completely in django ORM. You need two SQL queries:

1. Do your filter and collect a list of primary keys
2. Do an update on a non-sliced query set of items matching any of those primary keys.

Getting the non-sliced query set is the hard bit. I wondered about using [`in_bulk`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk-id-list) but that returns a dictionary, not a query set. One would usually use [`Q objects`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to do complex OR type queries and that will work, but [`pk__in`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) does the job much more simply.

```
latest_entry_ids = Entry.objects.filter(is_published=True)\
                                      .order_by('-date_published')
                                      .values_list('id', flat=True)[:10]  
non_sliced_query_set = Entry.objects.filter(pk__in=latest_entry_ids)  
n = non_sliced_query_set.update(views=F('views')+1)  
print n or 0, 'items updated'
```

Due to the way that django executes queries lazily, this results in just 2 database hits, no matter how many items are updated.

Comment: Note, these features will be available in the soon-to-be released Django 1.1

Comment: Yup, and they are already in the current svn trunk which many people use.

Comment: You can directly fetch the list of ids by using [value list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) :

    latest_entry_ids = Entry.objects.filter(is_published=True)\
                                      .order_by('-date_published')\
                                      .values_list('id', flat=True)[:10]

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume, I've put that in.

Comment: Here is how you import `F`: `from django.db.models import F`
I tried to edit in in but was rejected. This answer is easy to find via Google, but it's next to impossible to get to this information from here. It's not in the answer, not in the linked document, and also really hard to find via Google (because it's just one char).

Comment: @graup thanks for the suggestion, much appreciated. Edit made. (Wow 7 years ago!)

Comment: Do not forget to wrap both queries into "with transaction.atomic()" block.

Comment: Some versions of MySQL does not support `in` with a slice, try to convert `values_list` to a real list like this: `latest_entry_ids = list(Entry.objects.filter(is_published=True)\
                                      .order_by('-date_published')
                                      .values_list('id', flat=True)[:10])`

Answer (score 13):

You could handle the updates in a single transaction, which could improve performance significantly.  Use a separate function, decorated with @transaction.commit_manually.

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def update_latest_entries(latest_entry_list):
    for entry in latest_entry_list:
        entry.views += 1
        entry.save()
    transaction.commit()
```

Comment: I've implemented this, and though I can't notice any speed improvements yet, you tought me somthing new -- So thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you really need the efficiency, at the moment you'd have to drop down into SQL and run the update yourself.  That's not worth the added complexity in this case, though.

By Django 1.1 you'll be able to do this in a single SQL call via the ORM using [F() objects](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/c8cff7e5e16c692a/64f348822f2d43e5?lnk=gst&q=F()#64f348822f2d43e5) to reference fields in the update value.

Answer (score 2):

**Revised**

You're updating 10 separate, individual, distinct objects.

The 10 separate, individual, distinct updates can't easily be collapsed into one magical update that somehow touches 10 objects.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I'm new to Django and it seams I was confused. You're right there's no magical SQL call that'll do what I'm asking.

Comment: Um. Actually there is a magical SQL call that'll do what you're asking: UPDATE <table> SET views = views+1 WHERE ... Django's ORM can't do that for you yet, though.  Coming soon.

Comment: It seams I'm corrected again: (UPDATE blog_entry SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR ID = 3). Thanks Carl.

Answer (score 2):

A performance improvement to the previous entry. This results in one database hit, with a subquery.

```
latest_entry_query_set = Entry.objects.filter(is_published=True)
                                      .order_by('-date_published')[:10]  
non_sliced_query_set = Entry.objects.filter(pk__in=latest_entry_query_set.values('id'))  
n = non_sliced_query_set.update(views=F('views')+1)  
print n or 0, 'items updated'
```