# Django counting double

Tags: django, count

I've added a count field on my model, so that I can count when a user clicks on a specific button. However, my SmallIntegerField seems to count double each time I click on the button.

Any hints?

Model:

```
applicant_count = models.SmallIntegerField(_('Applicant Count'))
```

View:

```
job.applicant_count = F('applicant_count')+1
job.save()
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a `F()` expression? That is for referring to fields within a query. Try:

```
job.applicant_count = job.applicant_count + 1
job.save()
```

Comment: Got lost. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447117/django-increment-blog-entry-view-count-by-one-is-this-efficient.