# Mezzanine/Django hit counter for blog posts

Tags: django, blogs, counter, mezzanine, hit

I'm looking for something that can count and publicly display read hits on my Mezzanine Blog posts.

I'm coming from Drupal 7 where this functionality is built in.

I found `django-hitcount` and `django-tracking`.  Looks like they can both do the counting part but neither appears to have been maintained for some time.  I just need to make the app work with recent Mezzanine/Django and add the public viewing part.  Perhaps using a template tag.

stackoverflow has a public view counter.

Comment: This is not suitable for StackOverflow as this is not a specific technical question.

Comment: Erm, why do you need an app for this? Can't you just either have a field in your `blog` model called view_count and update it everytime someone views that particular post. Or you could have a separate model, with two fields, view_count and a foreign key to the blog model. Pass the views along to your template in the context

Comment: Or I could just install an app.....Erm

Comment: Read the Mezzanine documentation regarding model customization and field injection. Be ready to get your hands dirty.
Also, dig http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447117/django-increment-blog-entry-view-count-by-one-is-this-efficient for `F` objects and lazy queryset updates.

Comment: I found a different app that uses middleware and didn't have any problems.