# postgresql django: how to store an array of instances of variable type?

Tags: django, postgresql

Suppose that you're creating a blog and each blogpost consists of an array of interleaving text fragments and fragments of svg (for instance).

You store each of those fragments in a custom django field (e.g. `HTMLField` and `SVGField`).

What's the best way to organize this?

How to maintain the order of fragments? This solution looks ugly:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = CharField(1000)

class Fragment(models.Model):
    index = IntegerField()
    html = HTMLField()
    svg = SVGField()
    post = ForeignKey(Post)
```

Comment: Create a separate model to store those. You can't depend on fields because sounds like you don't know how many are there.

Comment: @ShangWang I'm trying to use one-to-many relation, but how to maintain the order of fragments? Just use integer field?

Comment: How many different types do you have? If you don't have many, your way is fine, use integer field to store the order.

Comment: I have 2 types. But while appending a post, I have to iterate over them all to find the one with largest index, if my post contains 20 fragments. I have to manually implement CRUD operations, which is wildly ineffective, compared to non-relational databases.

Comment: No, you simply do `Fragment.objects.filter(post=current_post).latest('index')` to find the largest index. If you want to go from first to last, do `Fragment.objects.filter(post=current_post).order_by('index')`. Just take advantage of ORM operations it's very easy.

Comment: @ShangWang 1) Thank you for discussion; 2) Ok, imagine that I remove an first element - I have to iterate over all the remaining and decrement index in them - that's pretty ugly; (same for insertion); also, to construct the whole Post from elements I have to iterate over them manually. Instead of array, I could also implement a linked list of Fragments, but that's quite troublesome, too.

Comment: The whole point is to store fractions and put them together later on, so I'm not sure why you are concerning iterating the whole queryset. Linkedlist is a very bad idea at the database level, you essentially have to do n fetch operations rather than one. You could use `F()` expression to increment/decrement multiple records in one shot, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447117/django-increment-blog-entry-view-count-by-one-is-this-efficient

Comment: @ShangWang Thanks a lot for your help. Please, post some of your comments as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, a separate model is a feasible way to go to record all the fragments. We use one `IntegerField` to record the fragment order, so that later one the whole `Post` could be recovered.

Some caveats here:

1. Use `order_by`, `latest` or slice n dice operations to sort/find elements.
2. When insert/delete operations are needed, it's going to break the overall sequence. We need to increase/decrease multiple elements to maintain the order. Use queryset and `F()` expression to change multiple records at once, like described in another SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447117/django-increment-blog-entry-view-count-by-one-is-this-efficient).

There are some imperfections about the approach, but It's the best solution I could come up so far(I encountered similar situation before). Linked list is a good way but it's not database-friendly, as to get all fragments we need O(n) operations instead of O(1) with queryset.