# django bulk update field with incrementing integer

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to bulk update one field of a queryset with an incrementing integer (not id)? Like `queryset.update(serial_no=i)` where `i=1,2,3...`

Django version = 1.11

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447117/django-increment-blog-entry-view-count-by-one-is-this-efficient

Comment: @Pedro Thanks for the link. I'll delete this one

Comment: @Pedro Actually my question is a little different, the update does not depend on any field

Comment: So you want to increase ```i``` on each iteration? The only solution I can think of is looping through the queryset.

Comment: https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update a bulk update plugin for django 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will actually work as I haven't tried it, but you should give it a go.

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber
from django.db.models.expressions import Window

queryset.annotate(
    row_number=Window(
        expression=RowNumber()
        order_by=F('ORDER_FIELD').asc(), # This needs to be set explicitly
    )
).update(serial_no=F('row_number'))
```

What this should do is select the row number which will be 1 for the first record, 2 for the second and so on. Then the update should use that value via the `F` expression to update `serial_no`. My only worry is that Django will break on attempting to do the Window annotation and update.

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: `cannot import name 'RowNumber'`. Maybe it is not in django 1.11